# Send a keyword to another keyword as a parameter

Tags: python, robotframework

I created a keyword which works similar to `Wait Until Keyword Succeeds`, so I want to send another keyword to it:

```
def keyword_expecting_keyword(self, func, *args):
    return func(*args)

def normal_keyword(self, arg):
    return arg
```

Now I expect to call `keyword_expecting_keyword` and pass `normal_keyword` as an argument:

```
Keyword Expecting Keyword    Normal Keyword    123
```

But when I do that, I get a `TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable`, so instead of Normal Keyword reference robot sends a function name.

Note: if it matters, <strike>I use an old-old RobotFramework 1.2.3</strike> (robot is v2.8, so it's OK, the ride GUI was v1.2.3)

### Updated With Real Code:

**Keywords code**

```
class ElementKeywords(object):
    def has_text(self, element):
        return bool(self.get_element_property(element, 'text'))

    def wait_until_result(self, timeout, poll_period, func, *args):
        time_spent = 0
        timeout = convert_time(timeout)
        poll_period = convert_time(poll_period)
        result = False
        thrown_exception = None
        while True:
            try:
                result = func(*args)
                thrown_exception = None
            except Exception as exc:
                result = False
                thrown_exception = exc
            if result or poll_period > timeout or time_spent > timeout:
                break
            time_spent += poll_period
            time.sleep(poll_period)
        if result:
            return True
        if thrown_exception:
            raise thrown_exception

        msg = 'Failed to receive positive result from {func} in {timeout} ' \
              'seconds'.format(func=func.__name__, timeout=str(timeout))
        raise TimeoutError(msg)
```

**Test case**

```
*** Settings ***
Test Setup        Web Setup
Test Teardown     Web Teardown
Resource          web_resources.txt

*** Test Cases ***
Check Index
    [Tags]    US123456
    Web Login
    Clean Redis
    ${job_id}=    Create Pool
    Web Refresh
    ${data_pool_element}=    Get Element By Xpath    //div[@id="progress-pool"]/div[1]
    Wait Until Result    20    1    Has Text    ${data_pool_element}
    Validate Pool    ${job_id}
```

**Stack Trace**

```
20150723 14:42:02.293 :  INFO : 
//div[@id="progress-pki-pool"]/div[1]
(None, u'//div[@id="progress-pki-pool"]/div[1]')
20150723 14:42:02.293 : TRACE : Return: <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x7f74173f2450>
20150723 14:42:02.294 :  INFO : ${pki_pool_element} = <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x7f74173f2450>
20150723 14:42:02.295 : TRACE : Arguments: [ u'20' | u'1' | u'Has Text' | <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x7f74173f2450> ]
20150723 14:42:23.315 :  FAIL : TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable
20150723 14:42:23.316 : DEBUG : 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/andrii/projects/automated-tests/library/keywords/element_keywords.py", line 88, in wait_until_result
    raise thrown_exception
20150723 14:42:23.317 : TRACE : Arguments: [  ]
20150723 14:42:23.317 : DEBUG : DELETE http://127.0.0.1:50355/hub/session/ee7b5402-a2fc-47fc-ade3-38c2c28cc208 {"sessionId": "ee7b5402-a2fc-47fc-ade3-38c2c28cc208"}
20150723 14:42:23.323 : DEBUG : Finished Request
```

Comment: You havent given us all the information, I suspect that you have a variable called `normal_keyword` that is set to unicode already

Comment: I tried to simplify the code, so it contains only the callable part. But I definitely have no variable Normal Keyword (in my case - no variable with the same name as the callable).

Comment: @Minras i think it would be nice if you give a full traceback  and your code

Comment: @VigneshKalai, I added the real code at the end of the question.

Comment: @Minras what about your full trace back

Comment: @VigneshKalai, I can't post full trace because it contains sensitive data, but I took the piece where that specific code is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`func` is passed in as a string, and you are trying to execute the string, which is why you get the error that you do. Simply put, you can't expect to do `func()`, it will never work because you aren't being passed a reference to a function.

What you need to do is get a handle to the built-in library, and use it to execute the keyword for you. I have no idea if this is possible with such an old version of robot.

The solution would look domething like this:

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
...
result = BuiltIn().run_keyword(func, *args)
```

The robot framework user guide mentions this in the section named [Using BuiltIn library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#using-builtin-library) and [Using other libraries directly](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#using-other-libraries-directly)

Comment: It worked, thanks! Well, in RF 1.2.3 the import looks like `from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn`, but the caller by name works.